# Openerp workflow doesn't show last transition button

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I tried to edit my holiday work-flow and up do '**validate**' state it is working fine. But then I have added new node with transition , then the transition button does not appear to validate the work-flow. Please help me with this and relevant codes are bellow.

***The last two nodes*** - hr_holidays_workflow.xml

```
  <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_validate"> <!-- accepted -->
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_holidays" />
        <field name="name">validate</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">holidays_validate()</field>
    </record>

    <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_new_validate"> <!-- last -->
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_holidays" />
        <field name="name">new_validate</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">action_new_function()</field>
    </record>
```

***The last transition***

```
<record model="workflow.transition" id="holiday_new_validate"> 
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_validate" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_new_validate" />
        <field name="signal">signal_last_validate</field>
        <field name="group_id" ref="base.group_hr_user"/>
    </record>
```

***Transition Button*** - hr_holidyas_view.xml

```
    <button string="Approved" type="workflow" name="last_validate" states="new_validate" class="oe_highlight"/>

    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,confirm,validate,new_validate" statusbar_colors='{"confirm":"blue","validate1":"blue","new_validate":"blue","refuse":"red"}'/>
```

**State declaration** - hr_holidays.py

```
 'state': fields.selection([('draft', 'To Submit'), ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),('confirm', 'To Approve'), ('refuse', 'Refused'), ('validate2', 'First Approval'),('validate1', 'Second Approval'), ('validate', 'Approval'),('new_validate','Appl')],
            'Status', readonly=True, #track_visibility='onchange',
```

***The function*** - hr_holidays.py

```
def action_new_function(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

        res = self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'last_validate'}, context=context)    
        return res
```

***UI***
Only refuse button is there not the "signal_last_validate" button
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was just I have used a wrong state in the button.

```
<button string="Approved" type="workflow" name="last_validate" states="**new_validate**" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

changed in to:

```
<button string="Approved" type="workflow" name="last_validate" states="**validate**" class="oe_highlight"/>
```